# ember-electron: Different assets compiled for ember and electron apps

Tags: javascript, ember.js, electron

I'm trying to turn an existing ember app to electron app using ember-electron addon. When I run `ember serve` and `ember electron`, files in `dist` and `electron-out/project/ember` are getting generated newly.

But the assets in these folders are different.

I'm using fingerprinted assets.

The assets expected by `index.html` file in `electron-out/project/ember` aren't present in `dist/assets` folder.

In `ember-electron/main.js`, I have the lines -

```
protocolServe({
  cwd: join(__dirname || resolve(dirname('')), '..', 'ember'),
  app,
  protocol,
});
```

and

```
const emberAppLocation = 'serve://dist';
```

From my understanding, there are separate assets compiled for ember-electron app whose `index.html` refers to ember-electron assets but trying to fetch them from `dist`.

What is wrongly configured here? Please help!